# How use a parameter as datasource in Jasper list element?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report template where a parameter is defined as:

```
<parameter name="phonenumbers" class="java.util.List"/>
```

Those phonenumbers are objects of type:

```
se.primenta.data.entity.PhoneNumber
```

and these objects have two methods that I need present in the report:

```
String getMaskedNumber();
Long getNumber;
```

I can't understand how to get these two fields into a subDataset that can be visualized in a List element. How do I write the dataset and the list definitition in the JRXML template?

Answer (score 5):

What about having a Datasource for the list like :

```
<dataSourceExpression>
<![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{phonenumbers})]]>           
</dataSourceExpression>
```

And then using 
$F{maskedNumber} and $F{number}

inside the list ?